# Hibernate error : Even after deleting composite keys from database

Tags: hibernate

I had deleted composite key from the table, but hibernate still complaints about the existence of the composite key. What else needs to be done?

Foreign key (FK44C80510FD020062:roleUser [roleUser])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (roleuser [idrole,iduser])

Answer (score 1):

Your DB is not in synch with your Hibernate definitions. Your schema definition contains a FK reference that is already changed on that Table. You need to update the Hibernate Schema and reload your structure into memory or restart your server.